# ARM TrustZone - Behaviour of the scheduler in Secure and Non-Secure OS

Tags: arm, trustzone

Can some one please explain to me that after the CPU is taken to secured mode, (Monitor program sets the `NS = 0`), how does the secure OS gets scheduled?
Is it that now that the CPU is in secured mode, the timer tick interrupt would be handled by the Secured OS and not the Non-Secured world?

Answer (score 2):

The monitor mode setting `NS=0` will set CP15 registers visible from monitor mode.  See: [monitor mode IFAR/IFSR...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080918/trustzone-monitor-mode-and-ifar-ifsr-dfar-dfsr).  When the *monitor mode* switches to another mode **and** `NS=0`, then the mode is the *secure world* version; meaning the banked CP15 registers are the *secure* version.  Also the `NS` bit is clear on *bus cycles*.

If `NS=1` is set, then when monitor mode switches, the banked CP15 registers are the *normal* version; mainly the *normal* world MMU will be active.  Also, the `NS` bit is set on *bus cycles*. <sup>[TZ vs hypervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485367/trustzone-versus-hypervisor)</sup>

> How does the secure OS gets scheduled?

Monitor mode does this.  The `SCR` (cp15 c1, c1, 0) has bits which determine whether the *monitor* vector table is used **or** the current CPU world (*secure* or *normal*).  If you are in a *normal* world and you wish for a timer to interrupt that world, you need *monitor mode* to handle it.

You can setup the monitor mode in two possible ways,

1. Have all secure interrupts as `FIQ`.
2. Trap all interrupts to monitor.

The first choice is recommended.  In this mode, the *monitor* code must ensure that `SCR#FIQ` (bit 2) is set in the *normal* world, but clear in the *secure* world.  The `SCR#IRQ` (bit 1) will be set when running the secure OS (if you want *normal* interrupts to interrupt the secure OS) and clear in the *normal* world.

So when the *secure* timer has a `FIQ` interrupt, it traps to monitor mode which does a *world switch*<sup>ref1</sup> and runs the *secure OS* timer code.  This *secure timer* may cause the secure world to reschedule.  The way the *normal* and *secure* world schedulers interact is up to software.  Ie, there is no generic answer.  It depends on,

1. Monitor mode
2. The *secure* OS.
3. The *normal* world OS.

Mainly the *ARM TrustZone* does not handle the *secure OS* scheduling by itself.  You need to write software that uses the primitives provided to implement this.  *ARM TrustZone* only facilitates different ways of implementing it. <sup>[TrustZone Whitepaper](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/PRD29-GENC-009492C_trustzone_security_whitepaper.pdf)</sup>

See: [How to develop programs for TrustZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455011/how-to-develop-programs-for-arm-trust-zone) for some alternative setups.
Ref1: A *world switch* saves/restores all general purpose CPU registers for all **used** modes.  Ie, on a *normal* to *secure* world switch, the R0-R15 (and all banked copies) plus possibly NEON/VFP must be saved to a *normal world* store.  Similarly, the registers must be reloaded for the *secure world*.  Monitor mode `sp` provides a good anchor for accessing these *world contexts*.  Monitor mode `sp` should be setup during secure boot, before the *normal* world initializes.  This is much like a traditional OS context switch.  The `SCR#NS` (bit 0) is set appropriately; you may do this before or after the register switching, depending on how you save the registers (Ie, by mode switch or by `srs`).

Comment: The above explanation of switching modes from NonSecure world to Secure World via Monitor is applicable in case both the worlds are running on the same physical core. Is this understanding correct? In case of multi core environment, if we have 1 dedicated core for TEE (assuming the secure OS is non-SMP) and another core/s for Non-secure world, does the working principle explained in your explanation change? I read the white paper from ARM - "Building a Secure System using TZ" (section 5.4). what happens when a SMC call is made in a Non Secure OS (running in a core other than TEE)?

Comment: Yes, of course.  If your question was how does a 'secure OS' get scheduled on a 2nd core, it wouldn't make sense.  Was that your question?  In this case, it is the same as AMP (assymettric multi-processing).  There is no need for the more expensive TZ CPUs, but just TZ-aware CPUs (Cortex-R, etc).