# What is partition checker in ARM Secure Mode

Tags: linux, arm, trustzone

As per this link
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/Chdfjdgi.html

under

System boot sequence
...

Program the partition checker to allocate physical memory available to the Non-secure OS.

What is the partition checker? Is it a subsystem which has registers, what is its programming model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the partition checker?

It is outside of the *TrustZone* specification for the CPU.  However, in a nut shell it partitions or divided memory spaces into different permitted accesses.  If the access is not permitted, it throws an *external BUS error*.

> Is it a subsystem which has registers, what is its programming model?

Typically, it is a bunch of registers.  It maybe multiple register files.  For instance, an APB (peripheral bus), AHB (older ARM bus) and a new AXI (TrustZone aware bus) may all be present in one system.  There may even be multiple APB buses, etc.

From the same page,

> The principle of TrustZone memory management is to partition the physical memory into Secure and Non-secure regions.

It should be added that *partitioning* the **masters** as *secure* and *non-secure* is also important.  The *partitioning* is outside the ARM CPU TrustZone specification; it is part of the BUS architecture.  It is up to a bus controller/structure to implement this.  The bus controller has both *masters* (CPUs, DMA peripherals, etc) and *slaves* (memory devices, register interfaces, etc) connected.

*Partitioning* in the context of the ARM TrustZone document is a little nebulous as it is up to each SOC and the bus controllers (and hierarchy) to implement the details.  As above, it partitions or divided memory spaces into different permitted accesses.  This is just like supervisor versus user access with traditional ARM ([AMABA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture)) AHB buses.  The AXI interface adds an `NS` bit.

Here are possible combinations for a *bus controller* to support.

```
             |  Read  | Write 
-------------+--------+-------
Normal User  | yes/no | yes/no
Normal Super | yes/no | yes/no
Secure User  | yes/no | yes/no 
Secure Super | yes/no | yes/no
```

The `SCR` `NS` bit will dynamically determine whether the 'NS' bit is set on bus accesses.  This is a *TrustZone* difference.  For the *super* and *user*, there is a traditional `HPROT` bit.  As well, each *master* will assert a WRITE/~READ signal (maybe the polarity is different, but we are software not hardware).

A DMA master (Ethernet, USB, etc) may also send out requests to a BUS.  Typically, these are setup and locked at boot time.  If your secure world uses the Ethernet, then it is probably a secure DMA master to access secure memory.  The Ethernet chip also typically has a *slave* register interface.  It must be marked (or partitioned) as *secure*.  If the *normal* world accesses the *ethernet* register file, then an BUS error is thrown.  A vendor may also make DMA peripherals that dynamically set the `NS` bit depending on the command structure.  The [CAAM](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/crypto/caam) is a **crypto** driver that can setup job descriptions to handle both *normal* and *secure* access, as an example of a DMA master which does both.

A CPU (say Cortex-M4 or Cortex-R) may also be globally *secure* or *normal*.  Only the Cortex-A series (and ARMv6) with full *TrustZone* will dynamically toggle the *NS* bit allowing the CPU to be both *secure* and *normal*, depending on context.

Slave peripherals maybe partitioned.  For example, the first 10MB of SDRAM maybe both normal and secure read and write for *inter-world* communication.  Then next 54MB, maybe normal only read/write for the normal world.  Then a final 64MB of read/write secure for the secure world.  Typically, register interfaces for peripherals are an **all or none** setup.

These are all outside of the scope of an MMU and deal only with **physical** addresses.  If the SOC locks them after boot, it is impossible for anyone to change the mapping.  If the secure world code is *read-only*, it maybe more difficult to engineer an exploit.

Typically, all APB buses are layered on an AHB bus, which connects to an AXI main bus like a tree.  The AXI bus is the default for a Cortex-A.  Each BUS will have a list of slaves and masters and will support various *yes* and *no* configurations, which maybe a subset of the list above; Ie, it may not care about *read/write* or *super/user* or some other permutations.  It will be different for each ARM system.  In some cases, a vendor may not even support it.  In this case, it maybe more difficult to make the system secure or even use TrustZone. See: [Handling ARM TrustZones‌](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334069/handling-arm-trustzones)​, where some of the bus issues are touched on in less details.

See: [TrustZone versus Hypervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485367/trustzone-versus-hypervisor) which gives some more details.

Comment: so does the SysMMU also have the NS bit?

Comment: I don't know the Exynos chip set that well; it could.  However, an [IOMMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU) is very similar, but different than a partition checker.  Typically the **IOMMU** is per-peripheral.  The [TZASC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0431c/Cacddhga.html) is a partition checker from ARM which is attached to the BUS controller.  The **IOMMU** is just like an MMU for a device.  For instance, the [Exynos5](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/product/application/detail?productId=7668) has a **TZASC** on chip.

Comment: [A paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11416-021-00413-y) on systems without TZASC.  Also, it is a good exercise to get all bus masters and peripherals and ensure you can assign them to worlds if they are not world aware devices.  You might want to write test code to ensure the peripheral devices are in-accessible at run time, if the world is forbidden.